# how can I change xml style in html page?

Tags: c#, xml

how can I change xml style in my html page?

for example in html DOM if we write : `document.getElementById("p1").style.color="red"`; we can change change color of this part but : `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("p1")[0].nodeValue.style.color= "red";` does nothing!!!

please help me!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style XML unless converting it to HTML ;for example something like:

```
<?xml-stylesheet href="style.css" type="text/css"?>
<quran> 
   <sura name="الفاتحة" index="1">
       <aya index="1" text="بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ"/>
       <aya index="2" text="الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ"/>
       <aya index="3" text="الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ"/>
       <aya index="4" text="مَالِكِ يَوْمِ الدِّينِ"/>
       <aya index="5" text="إِيَّاكَ نَعْبُدُ وَإِيَّاكَ نَسْتَعِينُ"/>
       <aya index="6" text="اهْدِنَا الصِّرَاطَ الْمُسْتَقِيمَ"/>
       <aya index="7" text="صِرَاطَ الَّذِينَ أَنْعَمْتَ عَلَيْهِمْ غَيْرِ الْمَغْضُوبِ عَلَيْهِمْ وَلَا الضَّالِّينَ"/> 
   </sura> 
</quran>
```

then in *style.css* :

```
aya{
    color:blue;
   }
```

[complete example](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/001/doc.xml)

or you can use [XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/).

idea from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8018471/2040375).

Comment: I don't want to add the style(for example fontsize) to my xml text at the begining of my program.Actually I want to add or change the style for example when i>5.Is it possible by XSLT?

Comment: @maedeharaghizadeh I think you could use `<xsl:if>`;see http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_if.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `Attributes` for example:

```
cell.Attributes["style"] = "direction:rtl;";
```

*I'm not sure that works!!!*

Comment: This is wrong. This overrides the complete style value. The intention in the code posted is only to change the color of style; but NOT the complete style.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work that way. `style` properties are for HTML DOM; whereas in XML the color on that style would be just the value of the attribute (Just as any other XML Data). You need to pick the style attribute on the XmlElement or XmlNode and need to find the index of `color:` and replace the value accordingly.

Comment: Can you explain more?My xml elements doesn't have any style.I want to change style of xml that is shown in the page,after an event.

Comment: Paraphrasing your comment - You have a scenario like this. You want to be able to change the font color on a label (which is not server control i.e., runat="server" attribute) after you click a button. Is this correct? Could you post the exact scenario you have?

Comment: I have a xml file,and in my html code I can access to my xml file and show the text and attributes,but I can't change style of this.Actually I want to change the size of text of xml file and show it.

Comment: My html code:<!--In the name of God-->
<html><head>
<script src="loadxmldoc.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc("quran.xml");
var txt1=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("aya")[0].getAttribute("text");
document.write(txt1);
xmlDoc.getElementByTagName("aya").style.fontSize="xx-large";
xmlDoc.getElementByTagName("aya").style.color="red";
document.write(txt1);
document.write("<br>");
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: and my xml code:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<quran>
<sura name="الفاتحة" index="1"><aya index="1" text="بِسْمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ"/><aya index="2" text="الْحَمْدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ الْعَالَمِينَ"/><aya index="3" 
text="الرَّحْمَٰنِ الرَّحِيمِ"/><aya index="4" text="مَالِكِ يَوْمِ الدِّينِ"/><aya index="5" text="إِيَّاكَ نَعْبُدُ وَإِيَّاكَ نَسْتَعِينُ"/><aya index="6" text="اهْدِنَا الصِّرَاطَ 
الْمُسْتَقِيمَ"/><aya index="7" text="صِرَاطَ الَّذِينَ أَنْعَمْتَ عَلَيْهِمْ غَيْرِ الْمَغْضُوبِ عَلَيْهِمْ وَلَا الضَّالِّينَ"/>
</sura>
</quran>